# How to insert data using insertMany() with DataType NumberDecimal in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have collection with field **price** that is of the DataType Decimal. When I use insertMany, how to set it to store in decimal type ?

```
let data=[{id:'1', price:10}, {id:'2', price:20}]
insertMany(data)
```

I user meteor and mongo node driver.

Answer (score 0):

To insert multiple document in MongoDB collection you can use the [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) method of [MongoDB driver for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb). Meteor provides `rawCollection` method to access to the the Collection object corresponding to the collection from the MongoDB driver module which is wrapped by `Mongo.Collection`.

In your case the query will be like this:

```
let data=[{id:'1', price:10}, {id:'2', price:20}]
CollectionName.rawCollection().insert(data);
```

Comment: yes thank but how to set value price 10 and 20 decimal type in mongo

Comment: it's already in `Number`, the javascript primitive for storing integers, floats, doubles etc

Comment: In mongo it used NumberDecimal function but mongo with meteor with raw collection I don't know what can convert it to decimal?

Comment: use as it is. you don't need to convert

Comment: If we use double number not decimal it will be Biased